# Install Virtual Box GuestAdditions on Debian 9.4.0 with Windows 10 Host

Tags: debian, virtualbox

Because it is not possible to change the display resolution on my guest `Debian 9.4.0 amd-64` running on `VirtualBox 5.2.8` on `Windows 10 64-bit`I tried to install the VBox-Additions from here: https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.2.8/

What I did:

- Add the .iso file of the GuestAdditions as CD-ROM in VirtualBox
  settings
- `su`
- `apt-get update`
- `apt-get upgrade`
- `apt-get install build-essential module-assistant`
- `m-a prepare`
- `sh /media/cdrom/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`

What I get:

[image]
The file `root/var/log/vboxadd-setup.log`:

[image]

The screen is still not resizeable, please help.

Comment: The module did not compile. Do you have the kernel source installed?

Comment: Works fine with VMware Player, I don't know why VirtualBox is so bad.